# 0 in the while statement

Tags: c++, coding-style, syntax, do-while

i have one question and please help me.i have read   on web page somthing  about do while  statement,different is that  ,in while  there is written 0,not boolean  condition

```
do{
   // do some instruction
}while(condition );
```

is  clearly  understandable,but this one

```
 do
  {
    //again some instruction
  }while(0);
```

i can't guess what does it do?is it equivalence it  to this: do something while(false)?or maybe  is it infinity loop?please help me

Comment: What's the context of the loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does something only once. It is [widely used in macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-mac) to group statements and make the usage more natural (i.e. require ending semicolon).

Any compiler worth its salt should ignore the do .. while altogether and just run the enclosed statements.

Answer (score 3):

Though this "loop" is executed just once, one may use it this way:

```
do
{
  // declare some local variables only visible here
  // do something

  if(TestSomeConditions())
      break;

  // do something more
  // destructors of local variables run here automatically
}while(0);
```

IMHO, in most cases it is better to rewrite this in a more structured manner, either this way

```
  // do something
  if(!TestSomeConditions())
  {
      // do something more
  }
```

or by introducing a separate function, reflecting the original scope:

```
  void MyFunction()
  {
      // declare some local variables only visible here
      // do something

      if(TestSomeConditions())
          return;

      // do something more
  }
```

Comment: +1: that's one of the reason. But it looks like "I want GOTO, but I've been told I cannot so gimme a loop to escape from!"

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: Yep, that was first coming into my mind when I saw this.

Answer (score 1):

The do while loop executes all the instructions in the body of the loop first and then checks for the condition. Hence, this loop just executes the instructions of the body of the loop once.

```
do
{
    //my instructions
}while(0)
```

is equivalent to writing

```
{
    //my instructions
}
```

The modern compilers are smart enough to optimize these things out!

Comment: Though this is true in many cases, technically this is not correct, since do{ - }while introduces a new scope.

Comment: ... but the question becomes another: WHY one should do that!

Comment: I agree! Editing my answer to reflect the same

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: see my answer for a possible explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It will treat 0 as false and one time loop will execute and break as soon as reached to while (g++ compiler tested).

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, it makes it run once, as it checks (and fails the check) after it runs once.

Other than that, it's used in macros. For example:

```
#define blah(a) \
        something(1); \
        something(2)

if(a)
    blah(4);
else
    blah(19);
```

would lead to this:

```
...
if(a)
    something(1); something(2);
else
    something(1); something(2);
```

which is not valid syntax, as the else is not part of the if statement anymore. What you can do is:

```
 define blah(a) \
    do {
       something(1); something(2);
    } while(0)

    ...
```

which would translate into a single statement in the if block:

```
if(a)
    do { something(1); something(2); } while(0);
else
    ...
```